# Reverse function of str_pad()

Tags: php

I have a simple code here using `str_pad()` function that will add 0 prefixes to a number. This is my code:

```
$num = 456;
$test = str_pad($num, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $test;
```

output:

```
000456
```

What if I want to reverse the code? If my number is set to `$num = 000456`, then it will output `456` only? Hoping for your kind consideration for my noob question. Thanks

Comment: `ltrim($test, '0');`

Comment: $test = (int) $test;

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
$val =  ltrim($your_num, "000");
```

Comment: The second argument is a character mask. So it's completely useless and doesn't do the same thing as `str_pad()`

Comment: So it should be just ltrim($your_num, "0"); then?

Comment: Then you get your desire number in 456 in $val

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = (int)$your_num;
```

Unless i am missing something, this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me.

```
$str = "0011";
echo (int)$str;
```

and output is 11